# Why this compile error

Tags: c#, compilation

Why if I write

```
void Main()
{
      string value = @"C:\";
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))  { 
            string sDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(value);
      }

}
```

it compiles.

And in case if I write

```
void Main()
{
      string value = @"C:\";
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        string sDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(value);


}
```

It doesn't ?

It's clear that from pure functional point of view the declaration of the variable in the *second* example is useless, but why it *magically* becomes usefull in *first* example, so ?

The IL code produced by both examples is *exactly* the same.

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "C:\"
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  call        System.String.IsNullOrEmpty
IL_000C:  brtrue.s    IL_0015
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     
IL_000F:  call        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName
```

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mantion that to produce the `IL` code for the second case (so the case which is **not** compilable),  it's enough to compile without `string sDirectory =`

Comment: Why would you want to create a variable that immediately dissapears like that?

Comment: Is this compiled in release or debug mode?

Comment: How do you get the IL for the second if it won't compile?

Comment: @David: Just remove sDirectory and compile :) Will edit the post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable declarations following if statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496589/variable-declarations-following-if-statements)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The production for an `if` statement is in section 8.7.1 of the C# spec, and it goes like this:

```
if-statement:
    if   ( boolean-expression )   embedded-statement
    if   ( boolean-expression )   embedded-statement   else   embedded-statement
```

The start of section 8 of the C# spec explicitly talks about the *embedded-statement* production after giving the specification for it:

> ```
> embedded-statement:
>    block
>    empty-statement
>    expression-statement
>    selection-statement
>    iteration-statement
>    jump-statement
>    try-statement
>    checked-statement
>    unchecked-statement
>    lock-statement
>    using-statement 
>    yield-statement
> ```
>
> The embedded-statement nonterminal is used for statements that appear within other statements. The use of embedded-statement rather than statement excludes the use of declaration statements and labeled statements in these contexts. The example
>
> ```
> void F(bool b) {
>      if (b)
>          int i = 44;
> }
> ```
>
> results in a compile-time error because an if statement requires an embedded-statement rather than a statement for its if branch. If this code were permitted, then the variable i would be declared, but it could never be used. Note, however, that by placing i’s declaration in a block, the example is valid.

Note that an assignment counts as an *expression-statement* - but a local variable declaration doesn't. (That's a *declaration-statement*, as in section 8.5.)

In terms of a design decision, it makes no sense to declare a variable that you can't then use - so it's *good* that the compiler stops you from doing it.

Comment: Agree, it's absolutely good that compiler stops me in second case. My question was about the *difference* of the first and second, but this, probably, leads to the question why {} is perfectly compilable case.

Comment: @Tigran: Hopefully my question answers the difference part - they're different types of statement, one of which is allowed as an embedded-statement, and the other of which isn't.

Comment: AS I wrote to David, the both cases are actually useless, and compiler is able to identify that , so why prefer one and not other? Why to make any difference between them ? That was *actually* the root of the question.

Comment: @Tigran: The compiler is able to identify that you've got an unused local variable in the first case, as part of a block - but that's a *semantic* analysis rather than just *syntactic* analysis.

Comment: It's actually not *quite* correct for the spec to say that the variable could *never possibly* be used. `if (x) int i = M(out i) + i;` would both write and read `i`; such a local variable declaration is exceedingly odd, but legal. What it really should say to be accurate is that the value of i *as determined by the value of the initializer* can never be used.

Comment: Because an empty block is perfectly legal, in C, in C++ and in C#.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: It's not clear to me which bit that's responding to.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Tigran's first comment, "...this,...leads to the question why {} is perfectly compilable case"

Answer (score 6):

Your second form tries to use what is effectively two statements (a variable declaration and a variable assignment) where only a single statement could be used. Think of it as:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    string sDirectory;
    sDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(value);
```

You can see this won't compile!

Comment: the *thing* is, that both cases **are** useless and compiler is able to understand it, so why prefer one and not other.

Answer (score 5):

The first version with the brackets declares a new local scope within which you declare a string variable, the second version doesn't - the variable declaration and assignment is interpreted as a single embedded statement which may not include variable declarations, hence the compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = @"C:\";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
string sDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(value);
```

The second statement is what is considered an embedded statement.. if you want to use sDirectory within what is called a "Code Block" wrap { } around it. inline statements like what you are trying to do in my opinion make for poor readability..

```
 string value = @"C:\";
 string sDirectory = string.Empty; should be even better way to code..
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
 {
     sDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(value);
 }
```

or this

both cases now should compile

```
  string value = @"C:\";
  string sDirectory = string.Empty;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     sDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for C#, but this is the case for other languages: because { } open a block and therefore a new scope. If you omit them, then the variable is being declared in the scope of `Main` and so will only be declared some of the time, and so the compiler doesn't know afterwards whether `sDirectory` exists or not.