# how to draw a line on a image?

Tags: c#, system.drawing

i want to draw a line on a bmp image which is pass into a method using drawline method in C#

```
public void DrawLineInt(Bitmap bmp)
{

Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

int x1 = 100;
int y1 = 100;
int x2 = 500;
int y2 = 100;
// Draw line to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

this give a error.So i want to know how to include paint event here 
(PaintEventArgs e  )

and also want to know how to pass parameters when we calling drawmethod?
example

```
DrawLineInt(Bitmap bmp);
```

this give the following error
"The name 'e' does not exist in the current context "

Comment: "this give a error". What error?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"Draw a line on a bmp image which is pass into a method using drawline method in C#"

PaintEventArgs e would suggest that you are doing this during the "paint" event for an object.    Since you are calling this in a method, then no you do not need to add PaintEventArgs e anywhere.

To do this in a method, use @BFree's answer.

```
public void DrawLineInt(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    int x1 = 100;
    int y1 = 100;
    int x2 = 500;
    int y2 = 100;
    // Draw line to screen.
    using(var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
       graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

The "Paint" event is raised when the object is redrawn.  For more information see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx

Comment: You should also dispose your pen once you're done with it. Or put it inside a `using(var blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))` block.

Answer (score 6):

You need to get the `Graphics` object from the `Image` like so:

```
using(var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
   graphics.DrawLine(...)
}
```