# Loading several images on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, image

Hi I'm writing an application using c# and I want to load one image and write some information in it.

There is a variable in my program named `cnt` where indicates numbers of images I should show .It means if `cnt==2` I should load image and put two different information in it.

Note : The image is a raw template for a certificate and I should load and show them based on some information of different certificates.

So how can I do it? Can `PictureBox` help me? How can I enable paging in it?

EDIT:

After reading from excel and get a match increase `cnt`:

```
foreach (DataRow drow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DataRow dataRow = (from DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows where dr["شماره کارت ملی"].ToString() == textBox1.Text select dr).FirstOrDefault();

    cnt++;
    string s = "" ,s1="",s2="",s3="";
    if (dataRow[0].ToString().Length < 17)
    {
        fname1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("write1" + dataRow[0].ToString() + s.PadLeft(16 - dataRow[0].ToString().Length, '.'));
        comport.Write(fname1,0,fname1.Length);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        fname2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("write4"  + s.PadLeft(14, '#') + dataRow[2].ToString().Substring(0, 2));
        comport.Write(fname2, 0, fname2.Length);
    }
    //do some other stuff
```

I want to show draw different information of a certificate on a certificate image template. If `cnt` is two the person has two certificates for two skill so the image template is the same but the skill information is different.

Comment: I presume this is a WinForms application?  Could you provide some sample code from where you're instantiating and using `cnt` in your form?  As it stands this question is pretty broad and hard to answer.

Comment: I edited and put some snipped code. The code is too long so I just put the `cnt` increasing part .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure I can help you.

1. Draw an Image Directly to the form (C# .NET) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt8Lk4LlTPA
2. How to draw a line on a image in C#? [how to draw a line on a image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402862/how-to-draw-a-line-on-a-image)
3. How to draw text on bitmap in C#? [c# write text on bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap)