# Draw graphical lines(lines composed of graphics) in Win Forms with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I would like to use GDI+ and C# to be able to draw lines consisting of images in WinForms.Please note that It is not to draw simple lines over an image but to draw lines made up of images like ***********************************(each * is a specific image).

For example, i have an imageA, and the line will be like imageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageA

Do you have an example or some advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to draw a line on a image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402862/how-to-draw-a-line-on-a-image)

Answer (score 1):

This question can be found with a little Google love in a couple of minutes. Try not to ask simple questions which have almost certainly been answered a hundred times over.

I searched for `c# draw line on image` in Google and the first link was a clean answer to your question

[how to draw a line on a image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402862/how-to-draw-a-line-on-a-image)

Even the MSDN method description of DrawLine has an example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain the question correctly.It is not to draw lines over an image but draw lines of images like *********************************** in which the line consists of many *.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the following
[image]

take the points of the star as lines. use the following function in Paint event.

```
void Draw(Graphics g)
{
   g.DrawImage(ImageObject, ptOrgin);
   DrawLine(objPen, StartPoint, EndPoint);//draw all line of the star
}
```

Every line has a start point and end point. GDI+ Draw line function needs two points 1. start point of the line and end point of the line and pen to draw. A star is a combination of line

ImageObject is the Bitmap.

Comment: Please add a usable code sample, or explain how `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` should be used.

Comment: Every line has a start point and end point. GDI+ Draw line function needs two points 1. start point of the line and end point of the line and pen to draw. A star is a combination of line.....

Comment: Thanks. In order to improve the quality of your answer, can you please include that information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to draw on your image:

```
public void DrawLineOnImage(Image image, Color lineColor, float lineWeight,
                            System.Drawing.Point lineStart, System.Drawing.Point lineEnd)
{
   // This methods draws a line on the image given as parameter

   try
   {
      // Check the parameters
      if (image == null || lineColor == null || lineStart == null || lineWeight == null || lineWeight <= 0) { MessageBox.Show("Invalid parameters!"); return; }

      // Draw a line on the image
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
      using (Pen pen = new Pen(lineColor, lineWeight))
      {
         // Draw the line
         g.DrawLine(pen, lineStart, lineEnd);
      }
   }

   catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
```

The start and end points are 2-dimensional coordinates.