# draw line on image without save image on server ASP .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

How can I draw a horizontal line over image on specific coordinate on asp page using c# code behind
this is my image code in aspx page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
 <!--Content Here-->

    <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" Width="900" Height="650" />

</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

can anyone help me

Comment: And where is your code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code-behind to draw line:

```
public void DrawLineInt(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    int x1 = 100;
    int y1 = 100;
    int x2 = 500;
    int y2 = 100;
    // Draw line to screen.
    using(var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
       graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

As refer to this: [how to draw a line on a image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402862/how-to-draw-a-line-on-a-image)