# Draw a line near image

Tags: c#, .net

Is this a fastest/simplest way to draw a line to the left and top of the image?

```
var srcImg = new Bitmap(@"D:\img.png");
var lineSize = 3;

var extImg = new Bitmap(srcImg.Width + lineSize, srcImg.Height + lineSize);
var extGfx = Graphics.FromImage(extImg);
extGfx.DrawImage(srcImg, lineSize, lineSize);
```

To get this [image] from this[image]

Comment: Looks like it to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402862/how-to-draw-a-line-on-a-image

Comment: @FelipeOriani That won't result in a bigger image, will it?