# calculate a vertical and horizontal histogram

Tags: c#, image

I'm new in `c#`. I want to draw a vertical histogram and a horizontal histogram from a png image.
Is that possible and what I should use.

Here is what I did, but I can't save it into a `bmp` image :

```
public void Histogramme (string roi_Path_png)
{
    Bitmap image = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(roi_Path_png);
    VerticalIntensityStatistics hist_vertical = new VerticalIntensityStatistics (image);
    Histogram histogram_vertical = hist_vertical.Gray;
    HorizontalIntensityStatistics hist_horizontal = new   
                                                   HorizontalIntensityStatistics(image);
    Histogram histogram_horizontal = hist_horizontal.Gray;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two parts for your solution.

1. To get vertical and horizontal histogram from image, Refer [Vertical Horizontal Aforge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597550/vertical-histogram-horizontal-histogram-in-aforge) for a detailed code block.
2. For saving the image as BMP, check out the Bitmap class, specifically [Bitmap.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save(v=vs.110).aspx) method from MSDN.