# Compiler Error CS1023

Tags: c#

My code won't compile with this error:

> Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

This doesn't compile:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)            
    DateTime xs = DateTime.Now;
```

but this does:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    DateTime xs = DateTime.Now;
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xaw06638.aspx) only explains the fact but not the **reason** why.

Comment: A clear explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496589/variable-declarations-following-if-statements

Comment: The MSDN page actually *does* explain it.
"An embedded statement, such as the statements following an if statement, can contain neither declarations nor labeled statements."

Comment: @TimothyGroote that's the quote in my question but that doesn't explain the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because it is a single line only, you are declaring a variable scoped within a for loop (which is subject to not execute under certain conditions).

So basically it is using smarts to say that it is impossible for you to use this variable within 1 line, so you need to declare it outside the loop.

Comment: error prevention by forcing the user to declare it outside the loop +1

Comment: The fact that the line might not execute is not really important.  For example, it's not an error to declare variables inside an `if (false) { }` block.  @Byyo how would forcing the user to declare it outside the loop prevent an error?

Answer (score 4):

It's because in the first instance you are declaring a variable that cannot be read.  The scope of the variable is the single embedded statement.  Therefore, declaring a variable in that statement is nonsensical.

In the second case, the variable's scope is a block, and other statements can be included in a block.  The variable can therefore be used.