# Unable to declare an ArrayList

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm not able to declare an ArrayList.  Here's my code. (I'd much rather use Lists, but I'm just trying to understand the concept of an ArrayList).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList salesTotals = new ArrayList();
    decimal[] decimalSales = { 1000m, 2000m, 3000m };

    foreach (decimal singleSales in decimalSales)
    {
        salesTotals.Add(singleSales);
    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get this error:

```
'ArrayList' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
```

I'm using the namespace `System.Collections` (not `.Generic`)

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Silly question, but did you accidently name your class `ArrayList`?

Comment: maybe your example code is in namespace that you called ArrayList? Could you try writing explicitly System.Collections.ArrayList in your code?

Comment: Not silly at all, George. The answer is "yes" :)

Comment: @Ray Well that will do it! :)

Comment: If you have enough time, read [this interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046012/companyname-foo-is-a-namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type/2330632#2330632) from Eric Lippert about a similar question.

Comment: An `ArrayList` basically works the same as a `List<object>`. That should pretty much cover the concept, so that you don't have to mess around with them any more. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the `ArrayList` within a namespace itself called `ArrayList`. The symbol is resolving to the namespace definition, which is invalid in the symbol's context, causing the error you describe.

Comment: sigh... I just proved my absolute "newbness". In visual studio, since I was trying to test a basic ArrayList, I called the project "ArrayList", which resulted in using a namespace with the same name. Thanks for pointing this out @mdm.

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best of us :-)

Answer (score 6):

One of the namespaces in your project is ArrayList.  This is causing the conflict.

Try changing the namespace, or fully qualifying it like this:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList salesTotals = new System.Collections.ArrayList ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cause you have a namespace defined with the name `ArrayList`. Change the namespace name to something different.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project called ArrayList?  That would do it.  The compiler is finding a namespace called ArrayList.  Try fully qualifying it ie new System.ArrayList();

Comment: It would be `System.Collections.ArrayList()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was saved the project name as `ArrayList` and when I was using `ArrayList` then it tells `ArrayList` is only namespace but not a type.

After changing the project name, now I am able to use `ArrayList` as a type. If you have taken the project name as `ArrayList` then you should have to change it to another name, I'm sure it will definitely work!

Answer (score 0):

error is depend on .net core version.
Path is right click on project=> Properties => choose .net core version in target framework.
Arraylist cannot use in lower .net core version.