# Visual Studio adding prefix to stated namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I'm getting a few:

'The type or namespace 'blah' does not exist in 'A.B.C' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The code looks like:

```
namespace A
{
   using B.C;

   public class Blah()
   {
      //...
   }
}
```

`A` and `B` are both assemblies that are included in the solution.  Both use .NET 4.0.  Assembly `B` does in fact have a namespace `C`. Assembly `B` is included as a reference in assembly `A`.

Why is it looking for `A.B.C` when the reference is `B.C`?

Comment: Would you mind providing a complete example with a skeleton for all the assemblies in question? Also, what line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Related question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046012/companyname-foo-is-a-namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type

Comment: @DanM, thanks... Eric's answer on that questions got me thinking about the problem differently enough that I could solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a typo in a different file than the ones with errors.

In another file I had:

```
namespace A.B.C
{
//...
}
```

I must have done an accidental Ctrl-P at some point?

The steps I took to find the offending file:

1. Open up the most recent file that I had changed
2. Examine the `namespace`
3. Repeat with the next most recent