# Why is using namespaces working in an unintuitive way?

Tags: c#, generics, namespaces

I've got a namespace in a referenced project, `Project.Base`, and someone thought it would be a good idea to declare their own generic List class in that namespace.

Now I have a code file that starts out:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Project.Base.Sub;
```

The `Project.Base` namespace is never actually formally used; just a nested namespace within it. `System.Collections.Generic` *is* formally used.  But for some bizarre reason, when I declare a method whose return type is `List<T>`, it interprets that as a `Project.Base.List<T>` rather than a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`!

This seems incredibly counterintuitive to me.  Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

**EDIT** To reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Project.Base.Sub;

namespace Project.Base
{
    public class List<T> { }
}

namespace Project.Base.Sub { }

namespace Project.Base.Sub2
{

    public class P
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<int>(); 
            Console.WriteLine(list.GetType().Namespace);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that the code in question is in a different sub-namespace of Project.Base.  This appears to be significant.)

Comment: Could you post the code for the Project.Base.Sub namespace? Or at least the beginning

Comment: In what namespace does the code that references the  `List<T>` exist?

Comment: `namespace Project.Base
{
 public class List<T>{}
}
namespace Project.Base.Sub {}

namespace Foo
{
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using Project.Base.Sub;
 
 public class P
 {
  public static void Main()
  {
   var list = new List<int>();
   System.Console.WriteLine(list.GetType().Namespace);
  }
 }
}`  Your problem as stated cannot be reproduced.  **Post code that actually reproduces the problem**.

Comment: @EricLippert \*facepalm\* I bet that's actually the problem.  I didn't even think to mention this, but the code referencing `List<T>` is in a different sub-namespace of `Project.Base`.  Edited now.

Comment: And now you can remove the `using Project.Base.Sub;` from your repro and see it still exhibits the same behaviour. That `using` declaration is a complete red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name lookup proceeds by searching up through enclosing namespaces, and only considering the `using` directives that are in scope of each one.

To make this compile, you can move your `using` directive inside:

```
using System;

namespace Project.Base
{
    public class List<T> { }
}

namespace Project.Base.Sub { }

namespace Project.Base.Sub2
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class P
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            Console.WriteLine(list.GetType().Namespace);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The top-level `using` directives are only inside the global namespace, and so would only be searched if lookup in enclosing namespaces fails. So, the first lookup fails to find a `Project.Base.Sub2.List`, but then at the next level, it located `Project.Base.List`. If that had failed, it would have tried to locate a `Project.List` type.

The other `using` directive was a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct. Another way to understand the problem is that your posted code is exactly equivalent to

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Project.Base.Sub;

namespace Project
{
  namespace Base
  {
    public class List<T> { }
    namespace Sub { }
    namespace Sub2 
    { 
      public class P
      {
        public static void Main()
        {
          var list = new List<int>(); 
          Console.WriteLine(list.GetType().Namespace);
          Console.Read();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now it should be clear why `List` resolves as it does. The declaration of `List` is directly in an enclosing namespace.

From a design perspective, it would be a good idea for you to push back on your colleague who thinks that naming a class "List" is a good idea. It is often stated that namespaces exist to prevent name conflicts, but that actually is their secondary purpose. In realistic code there usually are not very many naming conflicts, because people generally do not do confusing things like name their own class "List".

The primary purpose of namespaces is to *organize* code into logical groups, so that you can use `using` to "pull into scope" the names of the things you're likely to use in your program. This lets IntelliSense do a better job of figuring out what you mean as you're typing, makes the code easier to read, and so on. If you find that you're using namespaces to prevent naming conflicts, you might want to consider whether those conflicts could be eliminated by some tactical renamings instead.

Comment: Is what you posted actually valid?  I had no idea the C# language allows you to nest `namespace` blocks.  (99.99% of the code I've seen uses one `namespace` block to enclose the entire file, with the possible exception of comment headers and `using` statements, and the rest is either tests or examples.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The C# specification clearly states that `namespace Foo.Bar { } ` is *exactly* the same as `namespace Foo { namespace Bar { } }`.  The code is valid; I encourage you to run it if you have doubts. I note that I would not consider this code to be *good style*, but it is *valid*.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: If you are interested in learning more facts about namespaces that you do not yet know, you might want to read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/namespaces/

Comment: Class with the same name as the namespace?  Ouch! [Insert "why would you do that" meme here]

Comment: @MasonWheeler: This question might also be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046012/companyname-foo-is-a-namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type/2330632#2330632

Comment: Interesting puzzle.  I took one look at it and said "string", then looked again and said, "no, C is nested within a reified generic class, so it means that T in this context is statically bound as the type argument `int` before we even apply a type parameter to `A`."  That's not exactly the reasoning you gave in your explanation post, but it feels right.  Is that valid?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: In the post where I give the answer I note that almost everyone comes up with that explanation at first. Though it gets you the right answer, it's the wrong mechanism. T means T-from-A, no matter what. The real question is "what does B mean?"